# Is there a way to delete fields in Ag Leader SMS advanced if they aren't showing up in the management tree?

Tags: sms, qgis

I am having an issue with my fields in Ag Leader SMS.  I imported a TIFF image containing NDVI data and assigned it to a new field name, but it didn't show up in the management tree.  I put the TIFF into QGIS and figured out that it is not using the correct projection.

After getting this issue resolved, I wanted to reimport to SMS. However, the field is not showing up in the management tree, but when I go to device setup to make the export it is still there.

Basically, even though I deleted the branch, there is still a field in the export and I don't want a duplicate in future exports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I just ran into that issue recently as well, and it took some time to figure it out.

Basically, to remove a field altogether, you can't just delete the branch.

To completely remove it, whether you want to replace it with a new one or not, you have to remove all the files under it and then take it out of the field list.  The easiest way to do this is to right-click the field you want to remove and choose delete branch.  (This will remove it from the management tree, but there is still a record of it and that is why it shows up in the export still.)

Then, right-click a field that is still there -> choose "Alter Field List..." -> Under the Field category find the field you want remove -> highlight it -> click delete.

**If the delete button is greyed out, that means there is still data under that field.  You must delete the branch so that it is not showing up in the management tree before you're able to remove it from the field list.